# SQL trigger INSERT AFTER

Tags: sql, triggers, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I am trying to setup a trigger in phpMyAdmin. have two tables, one parent, one child. Every time a new user in `users` is created I want to automaticly create a line in the `permissions` table with the (AI) generated `id` from `users` as `user_id`. (`permissions.user_id` is a foreigh key of `users.id`)

users:

```
id    email              password
--------------------------------------
1     eric@test.com      sdgsdhdfhs
2     john@test.com      dfgsdgdfhg
3     mary@test.com      plkdfjvjvv
```

permissions:

```
index    user_id     allow_read   allow_write   allow_delete
-------------------------------------------------------------
1        1           1            0             1
2        2           1            1             1
3        3           0            0             0
```

I've tried (without success):

```
INSERT
INTO permissions
(user_id)
VALUES
(IDENT_CURRENT('users'))
```

and

```
INSERT
INTO permissions
(user_id)
VALUES
(@@IDENTITY)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are really using.  You have SQL Server constructs but a MySQL tag.

Comment: If it's MySQL, you can use `NEW.id` to access the generated id.

Comment: @GordonLinoff MariaDB / InnoDB

Comment: @PaulSpiegel It says (in phpMyAdmin) my hoster is providing MariaDB with InnoDB tables, but your method worked, much thanks!

Comment: MariaDB is fork of MySQL. The syntax is the same in like 99%

Comment: @PaulSpiegel How would one do this for a DELETE BEFORE trigger? 
This won't work: 
`DELETE FROM permissions WHERE user_id=DELETED.id`

Comment: In a delete trigger you would use `OLD.id`. However you dont need a delete trigger if you define a foreign key with `on delete cascade`. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the data of the row that caused a trigger to be executed, you can use `NEW` and `OLD` aliases. For INSERT triggers only `NEW` is available. For DELETE triggers only `OLD` is available. In UPDATE triggers you can use both. They are used the same way as table aliases (e.g. `NEW.id` / `OLD.id`).

Given a parent and a child table as follows:

```
create table parent_table(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    pdata varchar(50)
);
create table child_table(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    parent_id int not null,
    cdata varchar(50) default '',
    foreign key (parent_id) references parent_table(id)
);
```

To insert a child row when a parent row is inserted:

```
create trigger insert_parent 
    after insert on parent_table
    for each row
        insert into child_table(parent_id)
        values (new.id);
```

To delete all related child rows wehen a parent row is deleted:

```
create trigger delete_parent 
    before delete on parent_table
    for each row
        delete from child_table
        where parent_id = old.id;
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/EOW74217

However a delete trigger is not necessary if you define your foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE`

```
foreign key (parent_id) references parent_table(id) on delete cascade
```

All related child rows will be deleted without a trigger when you delete the parent row.

Demo: http://rextester.com/CWB43482